# Dynamic equal_to function unordered_map boost

Tags: c++, boost, unordered-map, boost-unordered

I have an unordered map string to int which uses a custom equal_to function defined as:

```
bool hashEqual::operator ()(const string &a, const string &b) const
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    return std::inner_product(
        a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
        0, std::plus<unsigned int>(),
        std::not2(std::equal_to<std::string::value_type>())
        ) <= 8;  
}
```

Basically what it does is if two keys have a hamming distance equal or less than 8, then is the same key.

The thing is I want the distance threshold to be dynamic in order to let the user set it through the command line. Instead of 8, a variable **threshold** or something like this.

I'm not looking for a hack like a global variable (unless it's the only way to achieve this) but for the "good way".

Comment: Does your operation actually define an equivalence relation?!

Comment: Yes it returns true if the distance between a and b is less than 8

Comment: So it's like E is equal to D and F, but not to Z... but F is equal to G, and G to H, ... and Y to Z... so is this transitive?

Comment: Actually it's some kind of clustering. The first string to be inserted will be a center and then the next ones will get into its cluster if their distance is less than 8

Comment: Such an equality function is not suitable for use with a hash table such as `unordered_map`.  Say you have one key/value in the hash table, then you try to find another key, there's a chance they'll "collide" to the same bucket - if they compare equal despite being different then your comparison will say it's found a match, and you may be able to modify the original value (e.g. sum the individual values).  But, the hash of the second value is more likely to map to a distinct bucket, such that no equivalence test is ever attempted.  There are *many* such issues - too many to list quickly.

Comment: But the map is only for a counting purpose. You think that case fails too? The collisions will add 1 to the position found (I check if the key exists with **find** and if it does, it'll increase the value by 1).

Comment: For you @TonyD you think for counting purposes it'll work? I'm using the same function for a multimap and it seems to work fine, but I'd like to know your opinion

Comment: @Jcao02: yes, it fails for counting, and so can multimap - most often when the first character is very different, even if the rest is identical - then there's only a small chance of a coincidental comparison as it compares to nodes near the root to work out which part of the tree to branch towards.  Try say "A123456" and "z123456" in a few different sets of ~10 keys - you should find it only works a few times at best.  Sadly, I don't think there's any *simple* and correct way to do the comparisons other than brute force (try every combination).  And results vary for same data in another order.

Comment: @TonyD I'm afraid I still don't understand why it fails. There's a way I can contact you for this? Because I'm having good results but not the expected ones and maybe it's because of what your saying!

Comment: I'll explain in an "answer", as it's too much for a comment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

All is done in the class hashEqual. I changed the definition like this:

```
class hashEqual {
    private:
        int th;
    public:
       hashEqual();
        hashEqual(int th) { this->th = th; }; // This implemetation on the .cpp
        bool operator ()(const string &a, const string &b) const;
};
```

the operator() implementation:

```
bool hashEqual::operator ()(const string &a, const string &b) const
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    return std::inner_product(
        a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),
        0, std::plus<unsigned int>(),
        std::not2(std::equal_to<std::string::value_type>())
        ) <= this->th;  
}
```

And in the constructor of the unordered_map:

```
boost::unordered_map<string, unsigned int, boost::hash<string>, hashEqual> myMap(size, boost::hash<string>(), hashEqual(threshold));
```

Answer (score 1):

### Why `unordered_map` doesn't work reliably

A good general-purpose hash function maps keys to buckets in a repeatable but otherwise seemingly random way, by which I mean that if the key varies by even a single bit then the bucket should be statistically unrelated - as if you'd picked another at random.  So, say you have a hash table with some existing elements:

```
[ bucket 0 - "abcde fghij" ]
[ bucket 1 - <empty> ]
[ bucket 2 - <empty> ]
[ bucket 3 - "01234 56789", "77777 QQQQQ" ]  (2 colliding values for this bucket)
[ bucket 4 - "XXXXX YYYYY" ]
[ bucket 5 - <empty> ]
```

If you come along to insert say `"Abcde fghij"` then you could hash to any of these buckets - you should have no more chance of that being bucket 0 than any of the others, but if that bucket is ***not*** bucket 0 then you'll ***never even attempt*** a hamming-distance-aware equality comparison against "abcde fghij".

---

### Why `multimap` doesn't work reliably

Imagine we a `multimap` with some existing strings (S1 through S6 in increasing lexicographical sort order - each with a hamming distance of more than 8 from the other elements) in it, the actual balanced binary tree might look something vaguely like:

```
            S4
          /    \
        S2       S6
       /  \     /  \
      S1   S3  S5
```

Now, let's say S1 happens to be `"Abcde fghij"`, S4 is `"ZZZZZ ZZZZZ"` and we go to insert `"abcde fghij"`:

- even with hamming distance comparison, `"ZZZZZ ZZZZZ" < "abcde fghij"` (remember that `'Z' < 'a'` in ASCII order) so the `multimap` expects `"abcde fghij"` to be stored in the right hand side of the tree...
- `"abcde fghij"` is then compared to S6, and if less S5, and will be inserted accordingly, but crucially there's ***never any comparison with S1***

---

Which brings me back to my earlier comment:

> I don't think there's any simple and correct way to do the comparisons other than brute force (try every combination). And results vary for same data in another order.